# How do I initiate App install for Bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

It looks like currently the only way to initiate an App install for Bigcommerce is for a merchant to click *Install* (or *I want this app*) under the [Bigcommerce App Store](https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/).

The Bigcommerce documentation just simply states "[The installation workflow is initiated when a Bigcommerce merchant chooses to install your app from the App Store](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/authentication#installation)".

Trying to start the OAuth2 process does work, but however, the Auth callback comes back with a bunch of missing data.  Specifically, if a request is sent to https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/authorize, it is redirected back to the [Auth Callback](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/callback), but is missing `context` parameter.    The initial request URL was created by [OmniAuth Bigcommerce Strategy](https://github.com/bigcommerce/omniauth-bigcommerce) and is includes an additional `state` parameter.  It seems like Bigcommerce does not support the */oauth2/authorize* request and it must be initiated by them via the App store.

Is the only way to initiate the install is to redirect the merchant to the App Store and tell them to click the *Install* button?

Comment: what are you receiving? and what is the issue

Comment: Updated with more clarification.  The question is simply "can only Bigcommerce initiate the App install process?"

Comment: Looks like the parameters being sent to *https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/authorize* are different.

Comment: Actually, it works, you can make OAuth request for the user and get a token back, but it is only for the user, not for the store.  So without providing the `context` (the store).  I did not see any endpoints that list stores per user.  Providing the `context` works and installs the App normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, no, you can initiate an App install externally, however you must provide the store you would like to install the App onto.  The `context` query string contains the store hash to initiate the install process (like this `stores/abcdefg`).

The problem I was having, was I receiving an authorization for access to the user and not the store.  Bigcommerce does not have an API endpoint to list stores by user (that I could find), so doing this really does not make any sense.

I was using the OmniAuth Bigcommerce Strategy, so I put in a [PR](https://github.com/bigcommerce/omniauth-bigcommerce/pull/8) to help with this issue.